# Average row values of a subset of columns based on (excluded) corresponding column value in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a neater solution for creating a column of row means for a selection of columns in my data, based on a condition of a corresponding column value. 
I've created some dummy data to show what I mean. 
Each row is a group of responses, and each numbered `A` and `B` are variables from the same response within the group.
I want to find the mean of the A values for each row, but only those who meet a criterion on their corresponding B value (eg. > 17).

```
df = data.frame(
  A1 = c(15,15,1,5,8),
  A2 = c(10,NA,5,3,10),
  A3 = c(NA,NA,6,4,10),
  A4 = c(NA,NA,5,5,NA),
  B1 = c(55,40,29,33,42),
  B2 = c(29,NA,18,11,26),
  B3 = c(NA,NA,14,8,22),
  B4 = c(NA,NA,11,16,NA))

> df
  A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4
1 15 10 NA NA 55 29 NA NA
2 15 NA NA NA 40 NA NA NA
3  1  5  6  5 29 18 14 11
4  5  3  4  5 33 11  8 16
5  8 10 10 NA 42 26 22 NA
```

So looking for something like this.

```
    mean
1 12.500
2 15.000
3  3.000
4  5.000
5  9.333
```

The solution I have so far is to create a new column replicating all the A values that I want to include, and then performing a `rowMeans` on those columns:

```
for (i in 1:4){
  A_inc = ifelse(df[,paste('B',i,sep='')] >= 17, df[,paste('A',i,sep='')],
                NA)
  df[, paste0('A_inc',i,sep = '')] <- A_inc
}

df$mean = rowMeans(df[grep('A_inc', names(df))], na.rm=TRUE)

> df
  A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4 A_inc1 A_inc2 A_inc3 A_inc4      mean
1 15 10 NA NA 55 29 NA NA     15     10     NA     NA 12.500000
2 15 NA NA NA 40 NA NA NA     15     NA     NA     NA 15.000000
3  1  5  6  5 29 18 14 11      1      5     NA     NA  3.000000
4  5  3  4  5 33 11  8 16      5     NA     NA     NA  5.000000
5  8 10 10  0 42 26 22  3      8     10     10     NA  9.333333
```

This works, but is cumbersome with my much bigger dataset and with more complex conditions from more columns (B,C,D and more). I know there must be a better way of doing this and was hoping to get some better methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowMeans` where you have overwritten the values where `!B>17`:

```
x <- df[,startsWith(colnames(df), "A")]
x[!df[,gsub("A", "B", colnames(x))] > 17] <- NA
rowMeans(x, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 12.500000 15.000000  3.000000  5.000000  9.333333
```

I assume that there is a corresponding B for each A.

Comment: I worry about how easy it will be to extend this approach to bigger datasets and more complex conditions and more columns. It will get really easy to make mistakes, and each time you want a slightly different specification, you will have to re-start from the beginning.

Comment: Can you give an example where it will come to problems?

Comment: How would you do a condition where you require that the mean of B is greater than a certain value conditional on B being greater than a certain amount? I guess more generally, I think it will get quite tacky to impose more and more conditions. I could certainly be wrong though!

Comment: But this conditions are not asked. I think it will work for *bigger datasets* and with *more columns* as it is.

Comment: also asked for 'more complex conditions', and my example could certainly be a desired condition. I mean if he just wants something like this specific example, then I totally agree your approach is fine, I just think that more generally, his problem is fundamentally about restructuring the dataset and then performing analysis on that rather than working with this current dataset.

Comment: As long as the *more complex conditions* are not given its hard to give a solution for it. Giving a solution for *conditions which are never required* might be harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

To accommodate a large amount of flexibility as you seem to desire, you need to fundamentally restructure your data. Once you have it in an easily manipulable form, you can easily do whatever analysis you want. So the costs come at the start to build this dataset, and then any operation is relatively cost-less. In particular, you want to use the data.frame capabilities of R, and so need to accordingly melt/cast your dataset so that each row is a groupXid observation with variables A and B. Below is one way to accomplish that, using `data.table`:

```
df = data.frame(
  A1 = c(15,15,1,5,8),
  A2 = c(10,NA,5,3,10),
  A3 = c(NA,NA,6,4,10),
  A4 = c(NA,NA,5,5,NA),
  B1 = c(55,40,29,33,42),
  B2 = c(29,NA,18,11,26),
  B3 = c(NA,NA,14,8,22),
  B4 = c(NA,NA,11,16,NA))

setDT(df)

#each group is a row, so define these groups
df[, group := 1:.N]

#melt where idvar is a group
df = melt(df, id.var = "group")

#variables are defined by the first letter you define, easy to adapt this accordingly
df[, vars := substring(variable,1,1)]
#individuals within a group are defined by the number, 
#ie the second character in the column names of your original dataset
df[, id := substring(variable,2)]
df[, variable := NULL]

#now cast so that each row is a groupXid observation, and columns are the variables vars
rdy_dt = dcast(df, group + id ~ vars, value.var = "value")
```

So you have the desired dataset, and now can use data.table's functionality to do anything you want. For example, to get the means, simply do

```
#condition is B >= 17, and we want the mean by group.
rdy_dt[B >= 17, mean(A,na.rm = T), by = group]
   group        V1
1:     1 12.500000
2:     2 15.000000
3:     3  3.000000
4:     4  5.000000
5:     5  9.333333
```

And you can basically combine any sets of conditions from multiple variables as such.